# I use JDBC to update the data but it doesn't work

Tags: java, jdbc, hsqldb

I try to use JDBC to insert and update the data. The insert function works well， but the update function didn't change anything in the database. There is no exception while running it.

I'm sure the RoomID exists and it is correct.

This is my insert function，this works

```
private static Connection conn;
private PreparedStatement pres;

public void saveRoom(Room room) {
    String sql = "insert into ROOM(roomid, object) values(?,?)";
    try {
        pres = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pres.setObject(1, room.getRoomId());
        pres.setObject(2, roomToBlob(room));
        pres.addBatch();
        pres.executeBatch();
        conn.commit();
        if (pres != null) {
            pres.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is my update function, this doesn't work. There is no exception but the data doesn't change.

```
private static Connection conn;
private PreparedStatement pres;

public void updateRoom(ArrayList<Room> RoomList) {
    String sql = "update ROOM set room.object= ? where room.roomid like ?";
    try {
        pres = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        for (int i = 0; i < RoomList.size(); i++) {
            pres.setObject(1, roomToBlob(RoomList.get(i)));
            pres.setObject(2, RoomList.get(i).getRoomId());
            pres.addBatch();
        }
        pres.executeBatch();
        conn.commit();
        if (pres != null) {
            pres.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I find the problem and solve it, but i still doesn't know why that happen.
My solution is：

Class A has a Arraylist list
public void update(){database.updateRoom(list);}

Class B ：
A a = new A();
database.updateRoom(a.getList());
This has no excepetion, but no data change in the database.

a.update(); this works well, the data change correctly.

Why this happens?

Comment: `pres` cannot possibly be null at the point you are testing it, so why test it? And why is it a member variable? This is just asking for trouble, as is having a static `Connection` variable. Both should be local variables, acquired and released inside the method. And why the batch for a single INSERT statement?

Comment: I've try = but it doesn't work.

Comment: How many rows were updated? What was the value of `roomID` in the INSERT statement? and the UPDATE statement? and what type is the `roomID` column?

Comment: Try using `where room.roomid = ?` instead of using `like`.

Comment: **Seven questions,** asked two days ago, and all you can come up with is reasserting your original unsupported assertion.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in comments, you need to change the UPDATE statement:

```
String sql = "update ROOM set room.object= ? where room.roomid = ?";
```

The `LIKE value` expression is used for matching parts of strings. For example you use `LIKE 'ma%'` when you want for find all the strings that begin with the letters `ma` (such as `mat`, `man`, `map`).

Comment: I tried = and like， but both of them doesn't work， i think it might because some rollback problem.

Comment: @SihongMiao I think it's because the `roomID` isn't the same. You need to answer the questions you're asked here.

Comment: @SihongMiao please update and answer the questions asked by user207421. If you try to update with roomID values that are not in the table, no data will change.